# Open up multiple app-id while using the google-chrome cli option

Tags: command-line, google-chrome

I wanted to open multiple PWA's (Progressive Web Apps) like Twitter, Google-Keep, and Youtube Music at the StartUp of Ubuntu.

There are particular app-id for each of the above sites, which are located as a folder at `~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Extensions/`

```
Twitter        - jgeocpdicgmkeemopbanhokmhcgcflmi
Google Keep    - hmjkmjkepdijhoojdojkdfohbdgmmhki
YouTube Music  - cinhimbnkkaeohfgghhklpknlkffjgod
```

So currently, to open these three PWA's at startup, I need to use three different CLI commands like the below at Ubuntu's `Startup Application Preferences`

```
/usr/bin/google-chrome --profile-directory=Default --app-id=jgeocpdicgmkeemopbanhokmhcgcflmi
/usr/bin/google-chrome --profile-directory=Default --app-id=hmjkmjkepdijhoojdojkdfohbdgmmhki
/usr/bin/google-chrome --profile-directory=Default --app-id=cinhimbnkkaeohfgghhklpknlkffjgod
```

How do I combine the above three commands to present an array of app-ids? I couldn't find anything in the man pages as well.

Is there any documentation related to the above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, I have resolved this by adding a shell script to Ubuntu's `Startup Application Preferences`

Adding `&` at the end of each line for spawning a new process for every command

```
#!/bin/sh

/usr/bin/google-chrome --profile-directory=Default --app-id=jgeocpdicgmkeemopbanhokmhcgcflmi &

/usr/bin/google-chrome --profile-directory=Default --app-id=hmjkmjkepdijhoojdojkdfohbdgmmhki &

/usr/bin/google-chrome --profile-directory=Default --app-id=cinhimbnkkaeohfgghhklpknlkffjgod &
```

But, this is not a long term scalable solution.

Answer (score 1):

The following code is modified from code based on [this site](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/use-command-line-arguments-in-bash-script)'s example.

### For your shell script

```
for appid in "$@" 
do
    /usr/bin/google-chrome --profile-directory=Default --app-id=$appid &;
done
```

### The command to call it

`sh my-script.sh jgeocpdicgmkeemopbanhokmhcgcflmi hmjkmjkepdijhoojdojkdfohbdgmmhki`

### Further Ideas

Have a configuration file that houses the IDs you want to open, and use the shell script to loop through the IDs in the config as opposed to the command line arguments.